# Exceptions to the molar mass trend in London dispersion forces in molecules: do they exist?

Tags: intermolecular-forces

"In general, larger molecules have higher boiling points than smaller molecules of the same kind, indicating that dispersion forces increase with mass, number of electrons, number of atoms or some combination thereof. "([https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/physprop.htm#:~:text=In%20general%2C%20larger%20molecules%20have,atoms%20or%20some%20combination%20thereof.](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/physprop.htm#:%7E:text=In%20general%2C%20larger%20molecules%20have,atoms%20or%20some%20combination%20thereof.))

My understanding of the statement above is that larger molecules (here I want to talk more specifically about larger molecules which are also molecules with larger molar masses than other molecules it's compared with) are likely to initiate more intermolecular interactions between other exact same molecules, creating stronger intermolecular interactions.

Are there any trends of boiling points of molecules not following the tendency in London dispersion forces that molecules with larger molar masses generally have higher boiling points than molecules with smaller molar masses? Please give examples if there are any. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"likely to initiate more intermolecular interactions"* -- No, there aren't more interactions; the interactions are just stronger. As for exceptions, water is probably the obvious one.

Comment: Recommend you just study more chemistry. The exceptions make up the interesting part.